# SKAction FadeOut, Change text, FadeIn

Tags: swift, skaction

I'm creating an intro monologue for a game. I was wondering how to use SKActions in a sequence that includes a text change.

I currently have

```
monologue.runAction(SKAction.fadeOutWithDuriation(1.5))
monologue.text = "text2"
//*wait for tap* (coded in)
monologue.runAction(SKAction.fadeInWithDuriation(1.5))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
extension SKNode
{
    func runAction( action: SKAction!, withKey: String!, optionalCompletion: dispatch_block_t? )
    {
        if let completion = optionalCompletion
        {
            let completionAction = SKAction.runBlock( completion )
            let compositeAction = SKAction.sequence([ action, completionAction ])
            runAction( compositeAction, withKey: withKey )
        }
        else
        {
            runAction( action, withKey: withKey )
        }
    }
}
```

**The code**:

```
var isMonologueReady : Bool = false //global var

monologue.name = "monologue"
self.isMonologueReady = false
let fadeOut = SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(1.5)
let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(1.5)
let changeText = SKAction.runBlock({monologue.text = "text2"})
let changeMytext = SKAction.group([wait,changeText])
let actionSequence = SKAction.sequence([fadeOut,changeMytext])
monologue.runAction(actionSequence,withKey:"monologueSequence",optionalCompletion: {
   self.isMonologueReady = true
})

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */

        let touch = touches.first
        let positionInScene = touch!.locationInNode(self)

        let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(positionInScene)
        print (touchedNode.name)
        if let name = touchedNode.name
        {
            if name == "monologue" && self.isMonologueReady
            {
                let fadeIn = SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(1.5)
                monologue.runAction(fadeIn,withKey:"monologueFadeIn") 
            }
        }
}
```

**Explanation**:

After you have create all base actions, you can choose what actions must be runned together on sequentially. As you can see in this code, `wait` and `changeText` are launched in group (parallel mode, together..) , after you can see a `SKAction` sequence based on the fadeOut and the `SKAction.group` named `changeMytext`. Finally, after a tap , if the `actionSequence` is terminated (boolean is true) so it's possible to run `fadeIn`.